# Why is typeof an "inline" function "function" and non-inline another variable type?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

Ever since I learned about callbacks/functions inside a function call, I thought they were identical with a function with a name.

But as I was testing, it looks like if both functions return a string, the inline callback-style one returns typeof function, but an actual function call returns typeof string. Let me demonstrate what I mean:

```js
function t(s) {
  return typeof s;
}
console.log("Inline function type: " + t(function() {
  return typeof "Hello world!";
}));
console.log("Non-inline with function name: " + t(t()));
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: so you are wondering why a sting is not a function? You just did `var x = t(); console.log(x); var result = t(x); console.log(result);` The equilivent would be `t(t)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpack `t(t()))` and you get:

```
t(t()))
t(t(undefined)))
// type of undefined is the string 'undefined', so you get
t('undefined'))
// type of 'undefined' is a string, so
'string'
```

The other approach:

```
t(function() {
  return typeof "Hello world!";
})
// equivalent to:
t(() => 'string')
```

In this second approach, you're not passing a *string* to the outer `t`, but a *function* that, when invokes, returns `'string'`.

```
t(() => 'string')
t(someFunction)
'function'
```